# Using protobuf from a Node native C++ addon and returning to V8

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, protocol-buffers, node.js-addon

I've been playing with Google's Protocol Buffers (protobuf) recently in my Node native C++ addon recently. My confusion:

How I can return my protobuf object from my C++ code to Javascript land, where it can be examined like a normal JS object? Is it possible?

Currently I am taking the inefficient approach of stringifying in C++ and parsing in Javascript, as in:

```
string stringified;
google::protobuf::util::MessageToJsonString(protobuf, &stringified, options);
Local<Value> argv[] = { Nan::Null(), v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), stringified.c_str()) };
Nan::Call(*callback, Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), sizeof(argv)/sizeof(*argv), argv);
```

Obviously this is not ideal and defeats the purpose. What is the correct way to return such an object to V8?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [protobuf](https://github.com/chrisdew/protobuf) module, which is a fork of [protobuf-for-node](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-for-node/) (which actually has usage docs). Basically, protobuf-for-node will make it easy to convert the protobuf into V8-managed objects right before your code returns to JS (iiuc), to save the JSON roundtrip. You could also create a Node Buffer from C++ to hand JS the binary data for the protobuf, and then parse it from JS, but I imagine the former approach will be faster.